# Confusion on Interface Workbook, Sheet and Row vs Classess XSSFWorkbook, XSSFSheet

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

Below is a simple code to access all the cells of an excel sheet.  I didn't use the classes
XSSFWorkbook, XSSFSheet...etc
My confusion is if an interface only holds signature of the methods then how come I'm able to
use methods like getRow, getCell using interfaces?

(where are those methods defined that are listed when I type sheet and then type period)

Thanks in advance.

```
 FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Eclipse\\WorkSpace\\YPractice\\TestCase.xlsx");
    
    Workbook guru99Workbook = null;     
    
    guru99Workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);                                 
    Sheet sheet = guru99Workbook.getSheet("KeywordFramework");
    
    int RowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum() - sheet.getFirstRowNum();
    

    for (int i = 0; i<=RowNum; i++)
    {

        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    
        
        for(int j= 0; j<row.getLastCellNum(); j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Data = " +i + " " +row.getCell(j));
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `XSSFWorkbook` implementation of `Workbook` when you do:

```
guru99Workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

Later you use `getSheet()` on `guru99Workbook`. Given that `guru99Workbook` is an `XSSFWorkbook`, you'll get in return a `XSSFSheet`.

This is similar to:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

To answer your second question, the methods are listed in:

1. `XSSFWorkbook`:
   [`getSheet(String name)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#getSheet-java.lang.String-)
2. `XSSFSheet`:
   [`getRow(int rownum)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getRow-int-),
   [`getFirstRowNum()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getFirstRowNum--),
   [`getLastRowNum()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getLastRowNum--)
3. `XSSFRow`:
   [`getLastCellNum()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html#getLastCellNum--)
   [`getCell(int cellnum)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html#getCell-int-)

Comment: This answer is wrong. In Java, it's not the runtime type of the object that determine which methods you can call on a variable referring to that object. It's the (compile time) type of the variable that matters.

Comment: @bruno, can you elaborate more on your comment? Why in this specific case would not be the same? Could this method be at runtime from a different implementation of Sheet (like HSSFSheet)?

Comment: You can add javadoc refs to explain your case more, eg [XSSFWorkbook.getSheet(String) returns XSSFSheet implements Sheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#getSheet-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I think example of "List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();" explains it well.  Thanks

Comment: @Gagravarr, as you suggested, I added javadoc refs

Answer (score -1):

The [`getRow(int)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) method is defined in the [`Sheet` interface](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html), and that's why you can call it from your `Sheet` `sheet` variable. Likewise, [`getCell(int)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-) is defined in the [`Row`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html) interface, and thus, can be accessed through your `Row`typed `row` variable.

Your intuition about how interfaces work in Java is perfectly correct. You may have misread the `Sheet` and `Row` interfaces' documentation.

Comment: Offcourse the methods are define in the interface. But at runtime, the methods of which implementation of Sheet would be called?

Comment: This is not what's been asked.